# Can't figure why my function is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I am trying to build a simple single page web app and I am stuck. I am trying to use the `module pattern` :

```
var spa = (function () {
    var initModule = function( $container ) {
        $container.html(
            '<h1 style="display:inline-block; margin: 25px;">'
                + 'hello world!'
            + '</h1>'
        );
    };

    return { initModule: initModule };
})();
```

Which in theory should be invoked here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SPA Starter</title>

    <!-- stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/spa.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/spa.shell.css" />

    <!-- third-party javascript -->
    <script src="js/jq/jquery-1.11.3.js">        </script>
    <script src="js/jq/jquery.uriAnchor-1.1.3.js"</script>

    <!-- my Javascript -->
    <script src="js/spa.js">      </script>
    <script src="js/spa.shell.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function() { spa.initModule( $('#spa') ); });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="spa"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to do `spa.initModule( $('#spa') );` in console and it's working, but in my code it isn't.

When I try to run I got `Uncaught TypeError: spa.initModule is not a function`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are calling the function before DOM is loaded. Try calling your function after document ready.

Comment: I tried to use `$(function() { ...  })` which is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`. Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: <script src="js/jq/jquery.uriAnchor-1.1.3.js"</script>  add > before script ending tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/AlexeiTruhin/4rg0mdgb/ - works for me.

It means you have an error, for example in declaring the script:

```
<script src="js/jq/jquery.uriAnchor-1.1.3.js"</script>
```

Close the < script ..>

Answer (score 0):

well,I met the same error,but the different reason that

I didn't insert "()" between "}" and ");" where in the end of the spa object definition.

Comment: Since it's *almost* the same error, do you think this might be a solution to the OP's problem with his or her code?